# rich:inplaceinput text color issue

Tags: richfaces

i have a problem with rich:inplaceInput
when i focus on a cell and unfocus the text of the inPlaceInput component turns gray
How to do to keep the text Black ?
please Help Me

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your code where you use the rich:inplaceInput component?

Comment: Hi here is the code : <rich:column id="Mother_Code">
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Nom du groupe" />
     </f:facet>
     <!--  <h:inputText value="#{file.mother_Code}" />-->
     <rich:inplaceInput defaultLabel="Click here to edit"
      showControls="false" controlsHorizontalPosition="left"
      controlsVerticalPosition="bottom" id="inplaceInputMC"
      value="#{file.mother_Code}" style="color:blue;">
     </rich:inplaceInput>
    </rich:column>

Comment: Please update your question with the code

Answer (score 0):

From what you write, i think that you using the blueSky skin and you are talking about the default text that is shown in the box in case it is not changed.
There is a css class (**rf-ii-dflt-lb**) for the default text that in blueSky it shows text in gray. You need to override this class in your page like

```
.rf-ii-dflt-lbl {
    color: black;
}
```

You can also check all css classes available for inplaceInput [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_inplaceInput.html#d0e35058)